# Merge Objects in a array and increase count

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

```
[{name:"abc",value:5},{name:"abc",value:10},{name:"abc1",value:5},{name:"abc1",value:15}]
```

I want to merge it by name so that the new array will be

```
[{name:"abc",value:15},{name:"abc1",value:20}]
```

Can i do it with es6 or a simple function

Answer (score 2):

Using `reduce` and without `find` or `findIndex`

```js
const data = [{name:"abc",value:5},{name:"abc",value:10},{name:"abc1",value:5},{name:"abc1",value:15}];

const summedDataObj = data.reduce((acc, entry) => {
  if (acc[entry.name]) acc[entry.name].value += entry.value;
  else acc[entry.name] = entry;
  return acc;
}, {});

const summedDataArr = Object.values(summedDataObj);

console.log(summedDataArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    name: "abc",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: "abc",
    value: 10
  },
  {
    name: "abc1",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: "abc1",
    value: 15
  },
];

const groupArr = data.reduce((r, a) => {
  const idx = r.findIndex((el) => el.name === a.name);
  idx === -1 ? r.push(a) : (r[idx].value += a.value);
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(groupArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can group the data by name using this function:

```js
function groupBy(arr, prop) {
    const map = new Map(Array.from(arr, obj => [obj[prop], []]));
    arr.forEach(obj => map.get(obj[prop]).push(obj));
    return Array.from(map.values());
}
```

this yields this result:

```js
[
    [
        {"name": "abc", "value": 5},
        {"name": "abc", "value": 10}
    ],
    [
        {"name": "abc1", "value": 5},
        {"name": "abc1", "value": 15}
    ]
]
```

which can be aggregated by using reduce on each resulting array:

```js
groupedData.map(entry=>entry.reduce((acc,cur)=>({
    ...acc,
    value: acc.value + cur.value
})))
```

so all together we get:

```
function groupBy(arr, prop) {
    const map = new Map(Array.from(arr, obj => [obj[prop], []]));
    arr.forEach(obj => map.get(obj[prop]).push(obj));
    return Array.from(map.values());
}

const data = [{name:"abc",value:5},{name:"abc",value:10},{name:"abc1",value:5},{name:"abc1",value:15}]

const aggregatedData = groupBy(data,"name")
    .map(entry=>entry.reduce((acc,cur)=>({
        ...acc,
        value:acc.value+cur.value
    })))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = [{name:"abc",value:5},{name:"abc",value:10},{name:"abc1",value:5},{name:"abc1",value:15}]

arr = obj.reduce((obj, item) => {  
    let find = obj.find(i => i.name === item.name && i.date === item.date);  
    let _d = {  
        ...item
    }
    find ? (find.value += item.value ) : obj.push(_d);
    return obj;
}, [])

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [{name:"abc",value:5},{name:"abc",value:10},{name:"abc1",value:5},{name:"abc1",value:15}];

const res = arr.reduce((obj, curr) => {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(curr.name) && obj[curr.name].name === curr.name) {
    obj[curr.name].value += curr.value
  } else {
    obj[curr.name] = curr;
  }
  return obj
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```